# Show that $(1+\frac{1}{n^2})^n \rightarrow 1$ as $n \rightarrow \infty$

Tags: sequences-and-series, limits

> Show that $\left(1+\frac{1}{n^2}\right)^n \rightarrow 1$ as $n \rightarrow \infty$.
> hint: $a^2-b^2=(a-b)(a+b)$

I basically have to show that $$\left|\left(1+\frac{1}{n^2}\right)^n-1\right| < \epsilon$$ but how do I choose $\epsilon$? Can anyone help me with that proof?

Comment: Hint: $\left(1+\dfrac1{n^2}\right)^n=\sqrt[n]{\left(1+\dfrac1{n^2}\right)^{n^2}}$.

Comment: This has been asked and answered before: https://approach0.xyz/search/?q=%24(1%2B%5Cfrac%7B1%7D%7Bn%5E2%7D)%5En%20%5Crightarrow%201%24

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you really need to use the hint, go to complex numbers.
$$\left( 1+ \frac{1}{n^2}\right)^n = \left( 1+ \frac{i}{n}\right)^n \left( 1- \frac{i}{n}\right)^n$$
Using the limit
$$\lim_{n \to \infty} \left( 1+ \frac{\alpha}{n}\right)^n = e^{\alpha}$$
valid for all $\alpha \in \Bbb C$, as $n \to \infty$ you get
$$e^i \cdot e^{-i} = 1$$

Answer (score 1):

This is equivalent to showing that the natural log of your sequence goes to 0 (Due to continuity allowing you to exchange the limit and the log)

Looking at the log,  we get
$$n \ln (1 +\frac 1 {n^2})=\frac {\ln (1 +\frac 1 {n^2})}{\frac 1 n} $$
now you have an indeterminate form 0/0,  so you COULD use L'hospitals, but it's much easier to do a variable substitution $u=\frac 1 n$ to transform your limit into
$$\frac {\ln (1 + u^2)} u \text { as }u\to \infty $$
Now you can use L'hospitals a lot easier.  Can you see how to finish from here?

Comment: Thank you for the answer, we did not cover L'hospital yet. I should've mentioned that there is a hint: $a^2-b^2=(a-b)(a+b)$ but I have not clue how to use that hint.

Answer (score 1):

According to the properties of limits, limit of a function raised to an exponent is a limit of a function raised to an exponent, and also, you can try to think how to get an $e$ in the limit

$$e=\lim_{x\rightarrow \infty} (1 + \frac{1}{x})^x$$

Here are the steps if you want to see...

> $$\lim_{n \rightarrow \infty} (1+\frac{1}{n^2})^n= (\lim_{n \rightarrow \infty} (1 + \frac{1}{n^2})^{n^2})^{\lim_{n \rightarrow \infty}\frac{1}{n}} = \lim_{n \rightarrow \infty} (e^{\frac{1}{n}}) = 1$$